# Flutter "Couldn't read file LocalFile: ... Even though it exists. Spotify playback plugin

Tags: ios, kotlin, flutter, dart, flutter-dependencies

Trying to use the `Spotify` Playback plugin but I keep getting errors when using trying to ad it the `pubspec.yaml` file. I have tried to use different versions of the package and have tried to update, pub, flutter, flutter clean etc. really not sure what the issue is. heres the full error in console:

Couldn't read file LocalFile:
'/Users/tobiasmuldoon/Dev/flutter/.pub-cache/hosted/pub.dartlang.org/spotify_pla
yback-0.0.8/android/src/main/kotlin/io/feesie/spotify/playback/SpotifyPlaybackPl
ugin.kt' even though it exists. Please verify that this file has read permission
and try again.

I have seen similar posts to this but none of the solutions seemed to work so sorry if this has already been posted. Any help is appreciated! (also I added the kotlin tag because that seems to be in the file directory, not sure if it is relevant, if not let me know)

Comment: Can you you read a test file you create manually?

Comment: This file is a test file where i'm having the issues, is that what you mean?

Comment: I mean, you're unable to read this file. Does it work if you try to read another file?

Comment: oh right sorry, yes I can, its only this one that doesn't work